# Webex: How to list hosts meetings

Tags: php, codeigniter, webex

Using PHP I need to get a list of company webex meetings and show them on web page

I tried the code on this page: https://developer.cisco.com/site/webex-developer/develop-test/xml-api/sample-code/

But that failed.

```
<serv:header>
    <serv:response>
        <serv:result>FAILURE</serv:result>
        <serv:reason>Failed to get SiteUrl</serv:reason>
        <serv:gsbStatus>PRIMARY</serv:gsbStatus>
        <serv:exceptionID>010000</serv:exceptionID>
    </serv:response>
</serv:header>
<serv:body>
```

Error message was that it could not find the SiteURL. The siteurl I was using is companyname.webex.com - when I put that url into browser, it goes to our webex page, so it seems to be correct.

I found this: http://joshuamcginnis.com/webex/ and tried it (using real credentials), but it gives a 500 error and I have no access to logs.

Both of these examples are very old and I am struggling to find up-to-date examples.

If I put  `https://company.webex.com/WBXService/XMLService` into browser, I get a success message

Can anyone suggest how to do this in either PHP or javascript

Comment: Add some code which will useful to take idea of your question

Comment: @Abdulla the code is in the link I showed at the start of the question

Answer (score 0):

According to the PHP example in the link, you must be using something like:

```
<securityContext>
  <webExID>YourCiscoUsername@example.com</webExID>
  <password>YourCiscoPassword</password>
  <siteID>243585</siteID>
  <partnerID>g0webx!</partnerID>
</securityContext>
```

Try using the "siteName" instead of "siteID", like the following:

```
<securityContext>
  <webExID>YourCiscoUsername@example.com</webExID>
  <password>YourCiscoPassword</password>
  <siteName>go</siteName>
  <partnerID>g0webx!</partnerID>
</securityContext>
```

You can use siteID or siteName indistinctly, but looks like that siteID isn't working for that demo site right now. Their Java and .Net examples are using siteName.

Now, you have to use "go" in siteName if you are making the request to https://go.webex.com/WBXService/XMLService

But you must use "apidemoeu" if you are making the request to 
https://apidemoeu.webex.com/WBXService/XMLService

They both appear to be demo sites.

And effectively "Failed to get SiteUrl" is the error returned if the value passed in either siteName or siteID doesn't correspond to an existing site.

Comment: How can get PartnerID?

Comment: It should be provided by Cisco to you. As you can see for the testing sites it is always: g0webx!